# How to read Data from CoreData using tool

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm new to CoreData. I want to know how to browse the data from CoreData of iOS Application.
I used sqlitebrowser but it is not showing up the database

Comment: Have you saved some data from your iOS app to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get you sqlite database your app folder by following steps through copy your database some where and open with help of sqlite-manager
Extension for Firefox and other apps to manage any sqlite database

STEP 1:

[image]

STEP 2:

[image]

STEP 3:

[image]

STEP 4:

[image]

STEP 5:

[image]

STEP 6:

[image]

STEP 7: Your App Folder

[image]

SETP 8:

[image]

SETP 9:

[image]